# Function is not defined node.js Uncaught Reference error

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In my app.js file I defined a function like this:

```
function testfunc() {
    console.log("Testing");
}
```

And in my home.html file I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./app.js"></script>

<div class="ProfileImage" onmouseover="testfunc()"> </div>
```

but when I mouseover the div it produces this

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: testfunc is not defined
```

Here is my file structure:

[image]

Comment: I think it should be testfunc without ()

Comment: @AhmedAlhameli — No. Mentioning a variable holding a function will have no effect

Comment: What does this have to do with node.js?

Comment: I need clarification since this does work locally. Are you deploying this to Amazon? If so, have you double-checked if the files are being deployed to the same folder?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your HTML File follows the below structure. I am unable to exactly answer as I cannot get your JS logs

```html
<html>

<head>
  ...
</head>

<body>
  ...
  <div class="ProfileImage" onmouseover="testfunc()">abcdefg</div>
  <script>
    function testfunc() {
      console.log("Testing");
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While there is no need to include `./` it does no harm so that won’t make a difference

Comment: I’m not asking anything. I’m telling you that your answer is wrong.

Comment: What is `app.js` is it something related to NodeJS?

Comment: Your syntax somewhat shows that you are mixing NodeJS and Browser side JS

Comment: what you should do in my opinion is to put both the html file and js file in the same folder and then test

Comment: @ahmed the html file and js file are in the same directory

Comment: @ath how do you mean? What part is js what part is node?

Comment: @MarshallScudder, I have updated my answer, try it out. I think it should work. (It is for troubleshooting the problem)

Comment: Yes but I need the function in my app.js file to store values to a different page

Comment: Even if you attach and external `.js` file it will work. I think you are doing something wrong with your directory structure. Your code is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your JS file is in the same directory as your HTML file. Otherwise it will not find it.

Comment: They're in the same directory

Comment: Check your function name and your js file name. And just to be sure its being imported, add an alert like this `alert("Hello from import");` in your JS file

Comment: the alert didn't show up. What does that mean?

Comment: It means your js file is not named correctly. Can you provide a screenshot of your file structure?

Comment: I added a screenshot of the directory

Comment: I don't know what the problem is now. And maybe since you're using ec2, why not add aws and ec2 into your tags as well

Answer (score 0):

Why did you forget that the internet is asynchronous? You want to run a function from a file that is not loaded yet?

If you want use events in this way, the JS code must be embedded in HTML.

If you want to do it right, read about `DOMContentLoaded` (JS execution after all HTML is loaded), `addEventListener` (event logging) and why JS scripts should be appended to the end of HTML.

Besides, I recommend that you be interested in `fetch ()` (Ajax replacement) and `document.querySelector (selectors);` (instead of `jQuery (selectors)`).

Answer (score 0):

### Edited answer:

It also looks like the file `app.js` is not loaded inside the file-`home.html`. Make sure your node.js server serves both files - `app.js` and `home.html`.

You may verify it by opening these URLs: `yourServerUrl:port/app.js` and `yourServerUrl:port/home.html`

- **Demo**: [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-dawn-5qucn)

### Old answer:

As mentioned in the question (node.js), it looks like you want to call a server-side function (i.e `testFunc()`) from the `home.html` file.

For that, please follow these steps:

1. Add the following code in your `app.js` file. This code creates an HTTP server to serve `home.html` and `testFunc()`

   ```
   const http = require("http");
   const fs = require("fs");

   function testfunc() {
     console.log("Testing");
   }       

   http.createServer(function (req, res) {

       if (req.url === "/testfunc") {
          testfunc(); //Trigger testfunc
          res.write("testfunc() triggered"); //return response to the client (optional)
          res.end();
       } else {
          //Return default web page
          fs.readFile(__dirname + "/home.html", function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
              res.writeHead(404);
              res.end(JSON.stringify(err));
              return;
            }
            res.writeHead(200);
            res.end(data);
          });           }

   }).listen(8080);
   ```
2. Add the following code in the `home.html` file. To trigger the server-side function, we've used the AJAX library.

   ```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div
      class="ProfileImage"
      onmouseover="askServerToCallTestFunc()"
      style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red;"
    ></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function askServerToCallTestFunc() {
        $.get("/testfunc", (resp) => {
          console.log("Response from server: ", resp);
        });
      }
    </script>
   ```

- **Demo**: [click here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-einstein-qf3vt)